# Create or simulate actual mirror using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

Since its not a real ray tracing environment, is it still possible to somehow create a mirror using ThreeJS? I'm trying to create a type of 'infinite reflection' environment, where mirrors reflect mirrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `WebGLRenderer.` See the three.js example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html.

You can create the infinite reflection effect if you edit the example, and move the mirrors so they reflect each other.

three.js r.63

Comment: Holy sh$t. thats kewl